Some questions at interpreting FRF from vibration test
Currently going through impact hammer test of cantilever beam(200mmx20mmx2mm) which is made of particulate composite(Epoxy/PZT/CB). Hammer sensitivity is 2.25mV/N and accelerometer sensitivity is 100mV/g. I'm trying my best to hit the same spot without skewing to get the average value in order to find driving point. Here are some problems I've been facing.

Shrinking magnitude at FRF

Let's say I attached the sensor at point A and hit the opposite side. I got pretty neat 2 sharp peaks with antiresonance placed between them. When I hit the same spot again, the 2nd mode peak of FRF dropped down to 0 which become barely visible peak. Same thing happend when I hit several more time. Can I say it's because of nonlinear result due to micro cracks and voids inside the beam? (I checked many voids by SEM image)

Phase

If I check the degree change from 60 to -120, then is it ok to assume resonance there? And does 360 degree changing and density of phase graph doesn't have any meaning at all? Lastly, does the 180 degree phase decrement going through long range of frequency mean high damping?

Coherence

I know the best result of coherence is mostly at 1 with slight drops at antiresonance points. In my case, the coherence is showing a noisy wave shape or like a thick dense phase graph. I've been trying to hit the same spot as uniformly I can. What is the cause of this result?
Thank you.

Can you give more details about the setup, such as how is the beam mounted in place, how hard did you hit the beam with the hammer?

@fibonatic Beam is fixed firmly using vise on normal table. Vise is clamped tightly on the table. I was trying to look out for driving point of beam. Range of frequency interest is under 200Hz. Since FFT device kept showing me the overload message even if I hit the beam softly, so I had to hit it with almost no force, about 0.02N. Impact hammer is 0.16kg, soft tip was used.

I think that 0.02N should keep the beam close to the linear region. How secure is the accelerometer mounted on the beam, could it have come loose or was it repositioned between hits? Could it be that the composite material is constructed in a faulty way, do you have access to a similar metal beam that you can test to verify the setup? Sensor placement and hit location should normally only affect anti resonances (assuming the sensor has negligible contribution to mass and stiffness). Unless that one anti resonance cancelled a resonance, it is weird that a resonance peak disappeared.

Without graphs illustrating each of these effects I'm not even going to try and understand. Have you done a linearity check? Have you optimised the compliance of the tip on the hammer for the frequency range of interest? " Can I say it's because of nonlinear result due to micro cracks and voids inside the beam?" maybe, but why wouldn't that affect the first mode as well?
